# Deleting a friend’s ECG related data

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, health.app

I let my friend borrow my watch to try out the ECG feature. However, now I want to delete all data collected while my friend was wearing the watch so it doesn’t appear in my health data. What items does it record and where do I delete them?

Answer (score 3):

It’s ideal if your friend only wears the watch for a short time during the ECG scan so that other background data isn’t collected.

1. Go to Health App
2. Show all Health data
3. Electrocardiograms (ECG)
4. Find the one that your friend took and note the time.
5. Choose “Delete Recording” on the ECG
6. Now go back to all data and find “Heart rate”
7. Select “Show all data”
8. Find the readings that took place around the same time as the ECG.
9. Swipe to delete all 30+ of them.

As far as I know, it only takes your heart rate and ECG readings while doing an ECG so deleting those records should suffice. However, it doesn’t hurt to look at all data and see if it happened to capture anything in the background around that same time. This is easier to find if you delete the data immediately after capturing the ECG since All Data sorts by the last time it collected data, making it obvious if something like Blood Oxygen happened to be taken in the background while your friend was wearing the watch.